# Using inspect.getsourcelines() for a module that is not stored in the same folder

Tags: python, python-importlib, dynamic-import, python-inspect

I have a module stored in some specific local location on which I am performing dynamic import using, `importlib` in python. After importing the module I am using `file.readlines()` to read all the lines in the file. If the file has a function called `foo` I want to get the source code of the function.

The program I am using, I have written below. When I use this program, I am getting error `NameError: name 'file_name' is not defined`

Note: I have separated file name from the location and hence I have written the `file_name` directly as a variable below.

```
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(file_name, file_location)
load_module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)

with open(file_abs_location, "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith("def foo"):
            line = line.replace("def ", "").replace("():", "")
            _name = file_name.replace("py", "")
            final_string = _name+line
            print(final_string)
            function_lines = inspect.getsourcelines(eval(final_string))
```

And I know that I am already reading the lines of the file and I can get function content from there but the problem is that I have to run this for many files and each file has different number of rows in `foo` function. So I cannot read a definite amount of lines after a function name.

Considering all my constraints, can someone please guide me on how to do this?

Comment: Sorry I think I'm missing something, is your problem that you are getting the `NameError` or something else?

Comment: My problem is simple. If I have a module which is in some other location, how do I get function inside this module using inspect.getsourcelines()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what your aim is but I think you are making it a bit more complicated than it needs to be. You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) on the module to find out if that function exists and if it does then get the function lines.

Here is an example to get the lines of the `merge` function in `pandas` (the superfulous use of `importlib` is just to more closely match the question above)

```py
import importlib, inspect
load_module = importlib.import_module("pandas")
if func := getattr(load_module, "merge", None):
    function_lines = inspect.getsourcelines(func)
```

Comment: Hello, I tried the method above. It given me an error ```module 'function_file' has no attribute 'foo'``` I know this means that the module has no function with the specified name. But, I know for a fact that this is not true. Is it because the way in which I am importing the module? Or is there any other explanation for this behavior? I am importing the module in the way I have shown because the module has special extension which behaves like a python file but is not a .py file.

Comment: I had to play around a bit with the program given in the explanation for importing the module dynamically using importlib. But, the overall logic I used is just like the one explained in the answer. Thanks for answering the question.